# Comparing the usage of Next.js 13's App router for fetching APIs in server-side versus client-side components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch, server-side-rendering, next.js13

Why is the response of Next.js 13 fetch API different for client and server components?

There's a query that fills in an ID number field in my backend.

When I tried to fetch data from the server component of the new Next.js 13 app router, I observed a difference in the data structure of the response compared to the client-side component.

**Inside NextJs 13 Server Component**

```
const getFeedPosts = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    "http://localhost:3001/posts/feed?page=1&limit=10",
  );
  if (!response.ok) throw new Error("Failed to fetch feed");
  
  return response.json();
};
```

```
export const Feed= async ({ category }: Props) => {

  const posts = await getFeedPosts();

  console.log(posts);  -->[{
      _id: '652a8027cb48f4991a6b9bee',
      authorId: '6529708b6d6bf058dc3ed201',
      title: 'Learn ReactJs',
      content: 'Learning ReactJs is fun',
      tags: [Array],
      createdAt: '2023-10-14T11:48:55.248Z',
      lastModified: '2023-10-14T11:48:55.248Z',
      __v: 0
    }]
  return <div></div> 
}
```

**Inside NextJs 13 Client Component**

```
'use client'
export const Feed= ({ category }: Props) => {
const getFeedPosts = async () => {
     const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/posts/feed?page=1&limit=10");
     const posts = await response.json();
     console.log(posts) --> [{
    _id: '652a801fcb48f4991a6b9beb',
    authorId: {
      _id: '6529708b6d6bf058dc3ed201',
      firstname: 'john',
      lastname: 'Dumlao',
      photo: ''
    },
    title: 'Learn ReactJs',
    content: 'Learning ReactJs is fun',
    tags: [ 'technology', 'science' ],
    createdAt: '2023-10-14T11:48:47.442Z',
    lastModified: '2023-10-14T11:48:47.442Z',
    __v: 0
  }]
}
useEffect(() => {getFeedPosts()},[]);
return <div></div>}
```

I used Axios in the server and client-side for fetching data. The data structure was consistent.

```
const getFeedPosts = async () => {const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/posts/feed?page=1&limit=10",);if (!response.data) throw new Error("Failed to fetch feed");

return response.data
};

export const Feed= async ({ category }: Props) => {

const posts = await getFeedPosts();
console.log(posts); --> [
{_id: '652a801fcb48f4991a6b9beb',
  authorId: {
        _id: '6529708b6d6bf058dc3ed201',
        firstname: 'john',
        lastname: 'Dumlao', 
        photo: ''
  },
  title: 'Learn ReactJs',
  content: 'Learning ReactJs is fun', 
  tags: [ 'technology', 'science' ],
  createdAt: '2023-10-14T11:48:47.442Z', 
  lastModified: '2023-10-14T11:48:47.442Z',
  __v: 0}
]

return (<div></div>)

};
```